# Scope not valid error when using ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder

Tags: azure, smtp

I am using ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder to get token and then send email

```
var pca = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
                     .Create(ClientId)
                     .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
                     .WithAuthority(AzureCloudInstance.AzurePublic, Tenant)
                     .WithRedirectUri(RedirectUrl)
                     .Build();




            var outlookScope = new string[] { "https://outlook.office365.com/SMTP.Send" };   // for graph use "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"

            AuthenticationResult result = null;

            try
            {
                result = await pca.AcquireTokenForClient(outlookScope)
                    .ExecuteAsync();
            }
            catch (MsalException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error acquiring access token: {ex}");
            }
```

But i get this error when on result
Microsoft.Identity.Client.MsalServiceException: 'AADSTS1002012: The provided value for scope https://outlook.office365.com/SMTP.Send is not valid. Client credential flows must have a scope value with /.default suffixed to the resource identifier (application ID URI).

What scope should i use to get token successfully, further i am using this smpt to send email

```
using (var emailClient = new MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpClient())
                {
                    var oauth2 = new SaslMechanismOAuth2(result.Account.Username, result.AccessToken);
                    await emailClient.ConnectAsync(SMPTServerName, SMPTServerPort, SecureSocketOptions.StartTls);  //google smtp.gmail.com
                    await emailClient.AuthenticateAsync(oauth2);

// Message Body 

await emailClient.SendAsync(message);
```

**Update**
Thanks to Rukmini, i was to able to get access token using

```
var outlookScope = new string[] { "https://outlook.office365.com/.default" };
```

Now the issue that i am having is to authenticate that token .
This is the code

```
  

    if (result != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Access token: {result.AccessToken}");
    
                    var message = new MimeMessage();
                    message.From.Add(new MailboxAddress("Sender Name", "sender@example.com"));
                    message.To.Add(new MailboxAddress("Recipient Name", "recipient@example.com"));
                    message.Subject = "Test Email";
                    message.Body = new TextPart("plain")
                    {
                        Text = "This is a test email sent using MailKit and Microsoft.Identity.Client."
                    };
    
                    using (var emailClient = new SmtpClient())
                    {
                        var oauth2 = new SaslMechanismOAuth2(result.Account.Username, result.AccessToken);
                        await emailClient.ConnectAsync("smtp.office365.com", 587, SecureSocketOptions.StartTls);
                        await emailClient.AuthenticateAsync(oauth2);
                        await emailClient.SendAsync(message);
                        await emailClient.DisconnectAsync(true);
                    }
                }
```

Now firstly result Account is null, so I get this error
[image]

Even if i put a random username, get this error `MailKit.Security.AuthenticationException: '535: 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful [DX0P273CA0070.AREP273.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM 2023-10-16T04:50:43.626Z 08DBCDB69CE3A094]'`
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the same code in my environment and got the **same error** as below:

[image]

[image]

> **Note** that: If you are using client credential flow to generate the access token, then the scope must have **/.default** as suffix to the resource. In your case the scope must be  **`https://outlook.office365.com/.default`**

**I modified the code like below to fetch the access token for outlook resource:**

```cs
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            string ClientId = "ClientID";
            string clientSecret = "ClientSecret";
            string Tenant = "TenantID";
            string RedirectUrl = "https://jwt.ms";

            var pca = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
                .Create(ClientId)
                .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
                .WithAuthority(AzureCloudInstance.AzurePublic, Tenant)
                .WithRedirectUri(RedirectUrl)
                .Build();

            var outlookScope = new string[] { "https://outlook.office365.com/.default" };

            AuthenticationResult result = null;

            try
            {
                result = await pca.AcquireTokenForClient(outlookScope)
                    .ExecuteAsync();
            }
            catch (MsalException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error acquiring access token: {ex}");
            }

            if (result != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Access token: {result.AccessToken}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

**Decoded token:**

[image]

**UPDATE:**

You can make use of Microsoft Graph API to send mail like below:

Grant API permissions:

[image]

Use the below code:

```cs
using Azure.Identity;
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.Graph.Models;
using Microsoft.Graph.Models.ODataErrors;

var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

var clientId = "XXX";
var tenantId = "XXX";
var clientSecret = "***";

var options = new ClientSecretCredentialOptions
{
    AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud,
};

var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
    tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, options);

var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);

var requestBody = new Microsoft.Graph.Users.Item.SendMail.SendMailPostRequestBody
{
    Message = new Message
    {
        Subject = "Test mail",
        Body = new ItemBody
        {
            ContentType = BodyType.Html,
            Content = "This is Test mail",
        },
        ToRecipients = new List<Recipient>
        {
            new Recipient
            {
                EmailAddress = new EmailAddress
                {
                    Address = "user@***.onmicrosoft.com",
                },
            },
        },
    },
};
try
{
    await graphClient.Users["user1@**.onmicrosoft.com"].SendMail.PostAsync(requestBody);
    Console.WriteLine("Successfully sent mail");
}
catch (ODataError odataError)
{
    Console.WriteLine(odataError.Error.Code);
    Console.WriteLine(odataError.Error.Message);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. But when i get the token, and i want to get authenticate it, i get this error

MailKit.Security.AuthenticationException: '535: 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful [DX0P273CA0070.AREP273.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM 2023-10-16T04:50:43.626Z 08DBCDB69CE3A094]'

Comment: This is my code 
using (var emailClient = new MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpClient())
                {
                    var oauth2 = new SaslMechanismOAuth2("User Name", result.AccessToken);
                    await emailClient.ConnectAsync(SMPTServerName, SMPTServerPort, SecureSocketOptions.StartTls); 
                    await emailClient.AuthenticateAsync(oauth2);

// Message Body 

await emailClient.SendAsync(message);

Comment: Try the code in the updated answer. The access token will not contain any username as it is generated without user interaction

Comment: Thanks again, please see the updated question for authentication error

Comment: Yes you are getting result.Account.username as null because the  access token will not contain any username as you are generating access token using confidential client flow that is there is no user interaction

Comment: So is there a way i can get it to authenticate ?

Comment: Check my updated answer and try the code. the result.Account.Username property will be null because there is no user context associated with the token. Instead, you can use the ClientId as the username when authenticating with the SMTP server otherwise make use of userinteractive flow

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255633/discussion-between-rukmini-and-its-siddiqi).